# iframe underlaps div footer

Tags: css, iframe, footer

I'm having some issues with my site, where the main iframe (100% height) underlaps the footer.
This causes the bottom of the page to be hidden by the footer.

I assume I've done something really odd, or plain stupid, with my code, and I hope someone can see the error that I have made.

HTML:

```
<html class="index">
<head>   
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,300|Playfair+Display:900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="heading">Header text</div>
<iframe src="menu.php" name="list" class="menu"></iframe>
<iframe src="dashboard.php" name="dashboard" class="dashboard"></iframe>

<div class="footer">20&copy;14</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

html.index {
    background: url(static/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

div.heading {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:36px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}

div.footer {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 90%;
    height: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 10%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 25px;
}

iframe.dashboard {
    border: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 25px;
    left:10%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:90%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    opacity:0.8;
}

iframe.menu {
    border: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bassmanpaul/sLuPx/)

The problem is you can't have a `top` & a `bottom` attribute set on your `iframe.dashboard` but you know the offset it needs to be which is **25px** (from the bottom) plus **50px** (from the top) so you can offset the height accordingly by **75px**.

See: http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Comment: This did the trick. Specified top: 50px, and did height: calc(100% - 75px);.